Bond Prices verse Yields
So maybe this isn't the right place for this question as it could be construed as an open-ended market speculation question the way I frame it, but I am trying to solidify my knowledge in regards to the open bond / treasury markets
I know the price of a bond / treasury and its' yield is inversely related.  So I was surprised to see when I pulled up the 2, /ZT and 10-year, /ZN futures quote that their quoted prices had decreased.
I would have expected the price of treasuries to go up due to more buyers in times of panic as was the case earlier this week in the equities market.
I guess it's possible people wanted to liquidate everything earlier this week? Even treasury holdings?
My concrete question relates to the yield and price dynamic... Am I thinking about it correctly that price affects yield not the other way around? What I'm saying is that an explanation for earlier this week IS NOT that investors demanded higher yields and thus treasury prices fell correct? Rather Investors were selling their treasury holdings forcing prices lower and yields to rise?
Thanks for the replies, and I hope this forum is the place for this type of question

Price and yield of a particular bond are inversely related and it is not meaningful to say which drives the other.  They are two ways of giving the exact same information.
Earlier this week prices rose as equity markets fell, the later this week bond prices fell as equity markets recovered.

The charts for /ZN and /ZT show 4 red days 8/5 through 8/8? That's whats interesting to me

Red means price decline and yield rise. As mentioned they go together, they are two ways of stating the same thing from a different point of view. A prolonged period of red days is a "bear market" in bonds,
